# Getting reset buffer jetty exception

Tags: spring, jetty, spring-web

I am using spring's DeferredResult with jetty (version: 9.3.11.v20160721) and getting this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot reset buffer on committed response
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:371)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:266)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I did google, which is telling that response is sent twice on same request, but I am having following check before setting any response, thus having this possibility shouldn't occur.

```
private DeferredResult<Object> result = new DeferredResult<>(10000);

  private void checkAndSend(Object res) {
    if (result.isSetOrExpired()) {
      log.warn("DeferredResult set/expired for res: {}", res);
      return;
    }
    ... // respsond
}
```

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You had an error, the HttpServletResponse was now in an error state.

The Jetty servlet engine was attempting to report the error to HTTP.
The first thing it does, is reset the buffer, so that it can then set the status and message to send the error response.

But it couldn't reset the buffer as the response was already committed. (something else had already started to send a response on that connection)

Comment: From my code I am not writing any response for sure. If it is already set then my code is returning. And I doubt there can be some issue with spring framework (as I can't find any related issue reported in jira)